# Android SDK Fragment Support

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-tabactivity

Ok i'm just starting to get into Android programming now, and I'm following the android "TabActivity" tutorial: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html.
Everythings working but it can't seem to find some of the support classes, see the code below that is generating the errors.

```
    mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
    mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"), 
            LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
    mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class,null);
```

For FragmentStackSupport/LoaderCursorSupport/LoaderCustomSupport/LoaderThrottleSupport, it says for all of them cannot be resolved to a type. I've added the latest support library to a folder in the root directory named "libs" and also coppied it into "C:/Eclipse/v4/" directory. My import files are:

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import android.R;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import cowdawg.hello_tab.namespace.R.layout;
    import cowdawg.hello_tab.namespace.R.id;
```

Could someone please offer me some advice on how to solve this, thanks :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably because the following classes are not part of the standard Android API (or the support library), but only exist in the support demos sample code for demonstration purposes:

```
FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment
LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment
LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment
LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment
```

You will need to add these classes to your own project in order to be able to use them. [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/index.html) you can find the source files under the subsection 'Files'.

- [`FragmentStackSupport`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentStackSupport.html)
- [`LoaderCursorSupport`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/LoaderCursorSupport.html)
- [`LoaderCustomSupport`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/LoaderCustomSupport.html)
- [`LoaderThrottleSupport`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/LoaderThrottleSupport.html)

Comment: Thanks MH, this was the most helpful comment so far, however i'm still running into some issues. I downloaded those java files, coppied them into my src file directory when my other code is. They showed some errors (with not being able to find certain functions), so i commented out the classes i didn't need and had errors but then it would produce a runtime error when using anything referenced in those files.

Is there another way i'm supposed to add those java files into my project?? I didn't think this would be so difficult.

Comment: It's probably easiest to grab the full source code to prevent any missing entities, like layouts and other resources. You can find the complete sample project in a subfolder of your SDK installation, more specifically: `[path-to-sdk]\extras\android\compatibility\v4`. Missing functions could potentially also indicate your build target is lower than required for the sample files, though I doubt that is the case here.

Comment: Thanks MH, I found the files and copied across the layout files and content (had to copy the actual files into my "src" file or it wouldn't find the classes, is that normal??). Anyways now onto the tricky task of working out exactly how to modify these tabs :).

Comment: if it doesnt come in the default android library then i dont think it is worth the trouble. I will look for another way that is supported natively.

Comment: They are example fragment activities. You can replace them with your own simple fragment activities if you don't want to grab the entire support library (which includes the samples) via the Android SDK Manager. For testing purposes, your simple fragment activities can be as simple as extending FragmentActivity and implementing an onCreate that sets a content view to anything really. Eventually you'll replace them with references to your real fragment activities anyway.

Answer (score 6):

On Eclipse IDE: Select your project and then right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library.

Required support library will be added on your project build path. You will found this library jar under Java Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Android Dependencies.

Enjoy exploring!

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the library to your build path? Right click on the jar in eclipse -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joakim, but yes I have already added it to the build path. Just then i actually deleted it and re-added it to the build path to no avail. I also right-clicked on the project and clicked "Add Compatibility Library" with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding by right clicking on the project and opening properties window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these missing classes you can create your own by subclassing `Fragment` class (or its subclasses like `DialogFragment`, `ListFragment` etc). More info is provided by Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).