# "FragmentStackSupport cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: android, tabs

Hello all,
     
I'm new to android. Today, I want to using "tab" in my app. Thus, I reference to the Android Sample Project.
     
There are some errors in the demo. First, I create a Support4Demos and I configure the "Build Path". I use Android Tools->Add Support Library. Then, the demo is successfully running.
     
However, this method seems useless on my own project. 
     
     
This is my code,

```
package com.example.wepay;

import com.example.wepay.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
                LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
                LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

These are my errors.

```
 FragmentStackSupport cannot be resolved to a type.
 LoaderCursorSupport cannot be resolved to a type.
 LoaderCustomSupport cannot be resolved to a type.
 LoaderThrottleSupport cannot be resolved to a type.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These are not system provided classes and will not end up in your solution.  It's just another part of the sample as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867134/android-sdk-fragment-support).